# making nested objects array and checking if the key exists in objs

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I am trying to check if the keys exits in array of objects. I am getting `false` each time when I pass existing key to my function.

```
var connect_clients = [];
connect_clients.push({
  'a': val
});

function lookup(name) {
  for (var i = 0, len = connect_clients.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (connect_clients[i].key === name)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(lookup('a'));
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What's `val`? Where does `.key` come from?

Comment: val is dynamic var lets say b and key comes from the loop inside which should be a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect_clients[i].key` refers to the actual property named `key`, not the keys of the object.

For this case, you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of keys of an object and use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to make sure that at least one of the objects has the key. For example,

```
function lookup(name) {
  return connect_clients.some(function(client) {
    return Object.keys(client).indexOf(name) !== -1;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys() to get keys of an object.

```
var val = 'val';
var connect_clients = [];

connect_clients.push({
  'a': val
});

function lookup(keyName) {
    var i;

    for ( i = 0; i < connect_clients.length; i++) {
        var keys = Object.keys(connect_clients[i]);

        if(keys.indexOf(keyName) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(lookup('a'));
```